# Only slow download speed in Wi-Fi client + AP configuration

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

I am trying to set up a local Wi-Fi network under a school Wi-Fi for our internal printer connection, etc. (~10-15 clients and not high bandwidth users)

[Network "Topology" diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuvYf.png)

Because the school network is enterprise type (PEAP-MSCHAPv2), I have to use a router (Router A) with 3rd party firmware as a client to connect to the school network (internet) before I can set up my local network. Since speed is also important in my scenario, I also added Router B to act as a dedicated access point.

However, I am still getting slow speeds (speedtest.net, same target server for all tests) from my clients under my local Wi-Fi network.

- MacBook client --> Wi-Fi --> School Wi-Fi (Down: ~280 Mbps, Up: ~240 Mbps)
- MacBook client --> Wi-Fi --> Router B (Down: ~50 Mbps, Up: ~150 Mbps)
- MacBook client --> RJ-45 --> Router A/B (Down: ~200 Mbps, Up: ~150
  Mbps)

Note that these speed numbers are an average of 2-3 tests in a short period. During different times of the day, the value could fluctuate and might be even lower.

Originally, I thought it was router B/A that was too old & slow, so I set up Test Case 2 and am getting similar results.

Do you gentleman have any idea what I am missing/setting messed up?
Or any suggestions on how to set up such a local network with the "right" hardware?